# Getting [debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError on updating selenium version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

The Automation suit was working fine before upgrading selenium to 3.9.1 . Once the selenium was updated, i am getting the below error on intializing Android driver.

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/abhinav.tiwari/Documents/Office Stuff/Automation/ui-automation-testing/TestData/mobile/testAutomation.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","fullReset":"false","noReset":"true","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/abhinav.tiwari/Documents/Office Stuff/Automation/ui-automation-testing/TestData/mobile/testAutomation.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","fullReset":"false","noReset":"true","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0"},"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"android"}]}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["desiredCapabilities","capabilities"]
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 5 ms - 178 
exception is .......org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["desiredCapabilities","capabilities"]
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
```

I am using 5.0.4 version of java client and 1.7.2 version of appium.
I did a lot of research on the internet, but could not find any solution.

## Below is the my code:

```
final File apkPath= new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"TestData"+File.separator+"mobile"+File.separator+"testAutomation.apk");
//Adding DesiredCapabilities
DesiredCapabilities androidCapability = new DesiredCapabilities();
androidCapability.setCapability("platform", testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("platform"));
androidCapability.setCapability("platformVersion", testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("platformVersion"));
androidCapability.setCapability("deviceName", testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("deviceName"));
androidCapability.setCapability("app",apkPath.getAbsolutePath());
androidCapability.setCapability("appPackage", testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("appPackageName"));
androidCapability.setCapability("appActivity",testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("appActivity"));
try
{
    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://"+testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("serverIP")+":"+testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("serverPort")+"/wd/hub"),androidCapability);

}
catch(Exception e)
```

Comment: Your code trials please.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you haven't mentioned from which version of *Selenium Client* you have upgraded to *Selenium v3.9.1*.

In the recent releases *Selenium* have evolved a lot. A few points :

- [*Selenium v3.7.0*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) :

  ```
  Migrated from using `DesiredCapabilities` to either `MutableCapabilities` or (preferably) `ImmutableCapabilities`.
  ```

The method which you have used `setCapability()` through [**DesiredCapabilities**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html) Class is inherited from the [**MutableCapabilities**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class. The current implementation of [`setCapability()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#setCapability-java.lang.String-boolean-) is defined as follows :

- `setCapability()`

  ```
  public void setCapability(java.lang.String capabilityName, boolean value)
  ```
- `setCapability()`

  ```
  public void setCapability(java.lang.String capabilityName, java.lang.String value)
  ```
- `setCapability()`

  ```
  public void setCapability(java.lang.String capabilityName, Platform value)
  ```
- `setCapability()`

  ```
  public void setCapability(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Object value)
  ```

While execution your program expects only the `"required":["desiredCapabilities"]` where as you have passed `["desiredCapabilities","capabilities"]`. Hence your program errors out.

### Solution

A solution for this issue will be only to send the supported `"required":["desiredCapabilities"]`. You may also use the [`merge(Capabilities extraCapabilities)`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) function from [**MutableCapabilities**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class and pass the arguments as **Options**

Comment: Previous version of selenium was 3.0.1 and now it is 3.9.1, i tried to use the class Mutable Capabilities but still it is throwing the same error.
Please help me how can i only send the supported "required":["desiredCapabilities"].